# Can i create a group or something like that in C using #define?

Tags: c, if-statement

I want to create a rank checking function in C. Like if the entered character is alphabet rank is incremented. If it is arithmetic operators then rank is decremented. I can create this by using `IF - ELSE` statement but to compare i would have to write every alphabet using `||` (or). I am trying to find a shortcut way.
I am looking for some thing like this:

`#define alphabets 'A'||'B'||'C'||'D' and so on`

`#define digits '1'||'2'|| and so on`

So when i use IF-ELSE it should be like

```
if(char[i]==alphabets)
      rank--;
if(char[i]==digits)
      rank++;
```

Comment: Lookup the `strchr` functions and the content of `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A `#define` as you have doesn't work like that. But there are functions in `ctype.h` that you can use: `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` are functions you are looking for.

```
if( isalpha((unsigned char)(char[i])) )
      rank--;
if( isdigit((unsigned char)(char[i])) )
      rank++;
```

Comment: What should i reaplace unsigned char with? Assuming char[i]='a' can u show me an example?

Comment: @Aditya I have shown it in my answer. It's a cast operation. You just cast the character to *unsigned char* while passing it to isalpha() and isdigit() functions.

Answer (score 3):

There are functions in the standard library for what you're trying to do:

```
#include<ctype.h>

if(isalpha(char[i]))
  rank--;
if(isdigit(char[i]))
  rank++;
```

Alternatively, if this is an exercise, you could define a [function-like macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html#Function-like-Macros) to do this:

```
#define alpha(c) ((((c) >= 'a') && ((c) <= 'z')) || (((c) >= 'A') && ((c) <= 'Z')))
#define digit(c) (((c) >= '0') && ((c) <= '9'))

if(alpha(char[i]))
  rank--;
if(digit(char[i]))
  rank++;
```

Comment: In modern C I would prefer to define functions instead of macros (assuming you are doing something that  is not already in the stdlib). If you insist at using macros, at least put parenthesis around the parameters, that is, use `(c)` instead of `c`.

Comment: @hugomg Agreed, I only included the second part in case this was some kind of assignment to write a macro. Good suggestion about the parentheses. I've edited to include that.

Comment: Also, note that the arguments to `isalpha()` and `isdigit()` should be cast to `unsigned char` to be safe. 2) The chars `'a'` to `'z'` and `'A'` to `'Z'` are not guaranteed to be consecutive (notable example is EBCDIC coding). So, the `alpha(c)` macro isn't safe either.

Comment: @hugomg i am trying to convert infix string to prefix. Its more like homework but i didnt want it to be lengthy. I will test out the answer and will see what i get as result.